# How to reduce a null validation code with java 8 and springjpa?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-data-jpa

I want to reduce the validations, maybe using some methods.

I'm delaing with a basic crud, and on the update endpoint, they want to update just one field at once, and giving me a arbitrary number of params, can be 1,2 or 10. and they dont want of course to erase the database if a parameter isnt sent.

```
 @PostMapping("/updateTask")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateTask(@RequestBody Task sentTask) {

        Task dbTask = null;

        try {
            dbTask = taskDao.findByIdTask(sentTask.getIdTask());

           if(isValid(sentTask.getAuthor())){
                dbTask.setAuthor(sentTask.getAuthor());
            }
            else{
                dbTask.setAuthor(dbTask.getAuthor());
            }

            if(isValid(sentTask.getIdReport())){
                dbTask.setIdReport(sentTask.getIdReport());
            }
            else{
                dbTask.setIdReport(dbTask.getIdReport());
            }
                taskDao.save(dbTask);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String response = "{\"data\": 
    {\"success\":\"false\",\"error\":\"Error updating the task:\"}}";
            return response;
        }
        String response = "{\"data\":{\"success\":\"true\",\"message\":\"Task 
      updated successfully\",\"Id\":\"" + sentTask.getIdTask() + "\"}}\n";
        return response;
      }


    public boolean isValid(Object data){
        if (data == null){
            return false;
        }

        if(data.equals("")){
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

I want some like this

```
   public void setData(Object sentData, Object dbData){
        if (isValid(sentData)){
            dbData.setSentData
        }
        else{
            dbData.setDbData
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Optional provided in java 8

```
Optional<String> authorOptional = Optional.ofNullable(sentTask.getAuthor());
if(authorOptional.isPresent()){
    dbTask.setAuthor(sentTask.getAuthor());
}else{
    dbTask.setAuthor(dbTask.getAuthor());
}

Optional<String> reportOptional = Optional.ofNullable(sentTask.getIdReport());
if(reportOptional.isPresent()){
    dbTask.setIdReport(sentTask.getIdReport());
}else{
    dbTask.setIdReport(dbTask.getIdReport());
}
```

**OR**

```
dbTask.setAuthor(Optional.ofNullable(sentTask.getAuthor()).isPresent()?sentTask.getAuthor():dbTask.getAuthor());

dbTask.setIdReport(Optional.ofNullable(sentTask.getIdReport()).isPresent()?sentTask.getIdReport():dbTask.getIdReport());
```

Now you don't need isValid or setData method

**I would recommend business logic related changes should be handled service layer**

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all the code like this

```
else {
    dbTask.setIdReport(dbTask.getIdReport());
}
```

doesn't make any sense as long as property value remains unchanged. So we could  easily throw it away.

2) Some reduction could be achieved with following approach

Add following methods:

```
public void updateTask(Task received, Task existing) {
    // run validations and copy only valid values
    copyValid(received::getAuthor, existing::setAuthor);
    copyValid(received::getReportId, existing::setReportId);

    taskDao.save(existing);
}

private <T> void copyValid(Supplier<T> getter, Consumer<T> setter) {
    Optional.ofNullable(getter.get())
            .map(this::validOrNull) 
            .ifPresent(setter); // setter will be executed only for non-null values
}

private <T> T validOrNull(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (data instanceof String && data.equals("")) {
        return null; // if data is invalid return null 
    }
    // additional checks for other types can be added here
    return data; // otherwise return data as is
}
```

And adjust controller method like this

```
@PostMapping("/updateTask")
@ResponseBody
public String updateTask(@RequestBody Task sentTask) {
    try {
        Task dbTask = taskDao.findByIdTask(sentTask.getIdTask());
        updateTask(sentTask, dbTask);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

P.S. As already mentioned in another answer you should extract your business logic to separate service